# How can a Linux server update it's time using Windows Server NTP service?

Tags: debian, windows-server-2016, ntp

I have a development server set up without connection to the Internet. (I update it using a makeshift http proxy only when required.) This afternoon, I realized that it's time was off of about 2 minutes.

Fortunately, we have a Windows Server 2016 with a NTP service active, so is it possible to synchronize the Linux development machine's time with the Windows Server 2016's time?

Answer (score 2):

Install `ntpd` if it is not already there and setup a `server` entry pointing to the windows system, then enable it and start it. It's not difficult.

Comment: alternatively, just run "ntpdate address.of.server" for a one off sync, or add it to cron if you dont need sub-second accuracy.

Comment: I have installed `ntp` (Debian) but there is no `ntpdate`